# Difference between VLingo and the built in Voice functionality in Android?

Tags: voice-recognition

My wife is contemplating an Android phone, and loved the demo she saw of VLingo on a Blackberry.  I keep noting that this is all built in and free on Android.  I imagine since they are cross coding anyway, might as well offer it for Android at least (It IS offered for Android, as well as iPhone and Blackberry).

So a couple of things:
What are the differences between VLingo and the built in functionality?
Are there other alternatives?

I like the Google technology currently used, and am playing with VLingo on my Blackberry, and am not so impressed yet.  I am waiting to be wowed.

Comment: I don't see how there can be a single, correct answer to this. You're asking for opinions, which is not the kind of questions we prefer on this site.

Comment: Agreed, this is subjective and should be closed.  And if VLingo hasn't actually been released for Android, this isn't really even an Android question.

Comment: I am asking for pro-cons.  Which is not exactly opinion.  And it was released for Android.

Comment: @Al Everett am asking for pro-cons.  Which is not exactly opinion.  And it was released for Android.   @Matthew Read : I edited to say that it has been released for Android.

Comment: @geoffc Pros and cons are absolutely subjective opinions, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Why would you" is definitely asking for subjective input. If you, perhaps, edited the question asking for objective details of the differences between the two products that would make it a better question.

Comment: @aL Everett Question topic changed.  I will edit it again to change it to list of differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried VLingo for a while on my Evo and wasn't impressed.  It did not seem to offer any value to me above that provided by the built-in voice actions.  I uninstalled it after trying it for a couple of months.

Comment: I can see why an iPhone, or BB would want such an app, I am trying to figure out how it improves upon Google included code!  Thanks for the response.   I think if I had to choose voice recognition code, I would choose Googles over most anyone, just knowing how they scale things...

Comment: @user921: Can you be more specific?